How to Prove an Inequality with Modular Arithmetic Indexing Criterion
For a given $n \in \{1, \, 2, \, ... \}$ and a set of values $a_{0}, \, a_{1}, \, ... \, a_{n - 1} \ge 0$ where $i, \, j, \, k \in \{0, \, 1, \, 2, \, ... \, n - 1\}$, the relation below is true.
\begin{equation}
\label{R-relation}
\sum_{k} \, \sum_{j - i \, \equiv \, k \pmod{n}} \frac{a_{i}^{2} + a_{j}^{2}}{2} \leq \sum_{i} n \, a_{i}^2
\tag{Ineq. 1}
\end{equation}
I am trying to prove \eqref{R-relation} as part of some other proof. In order to gain some intuition my first attempt was to write out the left-hand side of the relation for a few terms, and I noticed that we can alternatively write as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k} \, \sum_{j - i \, \equiv \, k \pmod{n}} \frac{a_{i}^{2} + a_{j}^{2}}{2} =& \ \bbox[10px, border:2px solid black]{\sum_{i} \frac{(n + 1)}{2} \, a_{i}^2} \\[0.5cm]
\leq& \quad \sum_{i} n \, a_{i}^2
\end{align}
Since it is a proposition in natural numbers so I even tried to go by induction, but two sides of the inequality did not make sense for me as one indexing is conditioned on modular arithmetic. My aim is to show that the framed term is equal(?) to its left-hand side. Therefore, my question is how I can approach this problem. What are some hints that I can take advantage of?

I disagree with your claim in the box. To me, I read it as $ \sum_{j - i \equiv k  \pmod{n} }  = \sum_{i, j, k \in [n-1]^3 } $ and so the sum is $ = n \sum a_i^2$. $\quad$ But of course, this means we have an equality instead of an inequality, so I guess I am misinterpreting what you wrote.

I have no idea as to what $\sum_{i, , j, , k , \in , [n-1]^3}$ means. Also how did you deduce what you have found?

It means $i, j, k \in { 0, 1, \ldots, n-1 }$ . For any $i, j$ value, there is some $k$ where $i - j \equiv k \pmod{n}$, hence there is really no restriction.

Is $k$ fixed, while $i,j $ are constrained by the condition on their difference?  If not, I don't see how $k$ matters.

There is indeed a misunderstanding so I just edited my post.
